# Unable to find the libc6-dbg_2.19-18+deb8u6_i386.deb package

Tags: apt, dependencies, glibc

I needed this package in order to install valgrind and I am trying to install it manually as a proxy setting on my laptop doesn't allow me to do 'apt-get'. Thus I decided to download and install the packages.

```
#sudo apt-get --print-uris install valgrind
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgssapi3-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libkdc2-heimdal
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gdb gdbserver libc6-dbg valgrind-dbg
Suggested packages:
  gdb-doc valgrind-mpi kcachegrind alleyoop valkyrie
Recommended packages:
  libc-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gdb gdbserver libc6-dbg valgrind valgrind-dbg
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 171 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gdb/gdb_7.7.1+dfsg-5_i386.deb' gdb_7.7.1+dfsg-5_i386.deb 2332462 MD5Sum:276b7879742b9be00767201b2bec2634
'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gdb/gdbserver_7.7.1+dfsg-5_i386.deb' gdbserver_7.7.1+dfsg-5_i386.deb 252128 MD5Sum:f3b56313995d9c07dae0893b2d2d6707
'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dbg_2.19-18+deb8u6_i386.deb' libc6-dbg_2.19-18+deb8u6_i386.deb 8126138 MD5Sum:0fc1f837a51bedecfa8c3e05a32fd6e7
'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/valgrind/valgrind_3.10.0-4_i386.deb' valgrind_1%3a3.10.0-4_i386.deb 6730270 MD5Sum:ea7c2d01c896c39ce22b34208eee0f42
'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/valgrind/valgrind-dbg_3.10.0-4_i386.deb' valgrind-dbg_1%3a3.10.0-4_i386.deb 9420490 MD5Sum:fdb6b51ec4a4d114c649f83e8388ae41
```

I checked this above website links and didn't find glibc/libc6-dbg_2.19-18+deb8u6_i386.deb in there. I am able to find libc6-dbg_2.19-18+deb8u**10**_i386.deb. But I need libc6-dbg_2.19-18+deb8u**6**_i386.deb. How can I download this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it from [snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/glibc/2.19-18%2Bdeb8u6/#libc6-dbg_2.19-18:2b:deb8u6):

```
wget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20160905T103837Z/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dbg_2.19-18%2Bdeb8u6_i386.deb
```

Ideally, you should upgrade your system with the latest Debian 8 updates; that would avoid this issue.